# Table 'performance_schema.threads' doesn't exist. SQL Error: 1146)

Tags: mysql-5.6, windows-server

I'm using MySQL '5.6.29-log' on Windows 2012 and `performance_schema` is missing 
few tables.

How does I re create `performance_schema`? I'm looking at [MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual :: 22.2.1 Performance Schema Build Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-build-configuration.html) and  I cannot find anything(

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**mysql_upgrade** — Check and Upgrade MySQL Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html)